# gdb add-symbol-file all sections and load address

Tags: gdb, debug-symbols

I'm debugging a boot loader (syslinux) with gdb and the gdb-stub of qemu. At some point the main file load a shared object `ldlinux.elf`.

I would like to add the symbols in gdb for that file. The command `add-symbol-file` seems like the way to go. However, as a relocatable file, I have to specify the memory address it has been loaded at. And here comes the problem.

Although I know the base address at which the `LOAD` segment has been loaded at, `add-symbol-file` works section-wise and want me to specify the address at which each section has been loaded.

Can I tell gdb to load all the symbols of all the sections provided that I specify the base address of the file in memory?

Does the behavior of gdb make sens? The section headers aren't used for running an ELF and are even optional. I can't see a use case where specifying the load address of the sections would be useful.

---

### Example

Here are the program headers and section headers of the shared object.

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x4c60
There are 3 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x1db10 0x20bfc RWE 0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x01d618 0x0001d618 0x0001d618 0x00098 0x00098 RW  0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RWE 0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .rel.dyn .rel.plt .plt .text .rodata .ctors .dtors .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   01     .dynamic 
   02
```

```
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x78618:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        00000094 000094 0007e0 04   A  2   0  4
  [ 2] .dynsym           DYNSYM          00000874 000874 0015c0 10   A  3   1  4
  [ 3] .dynstr           STRTAB          00001e34 001e34 0010f4 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 4] .rel.dyn          REL             00002f28 002f28 000ce8 08   A  2   0  4
  [ 5] .rel.plt          REL             00003c10 003c10 000568 08  AI  2   6  4
  [ 6] .plt              PROGBITS        00004180 004180 000ae0 04  AX  0   0 16
  [ 7] .text             PROGBITS        00004c60 004c60 013816 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 8] .rodata           PROGBITS        00018480 018480 00462f 00   A  0   0 32
  [ 9] .ctors            INIT_ARRAY      0001cab0 01cab0 000010 00  WA  0   0  4
  [10] .dtors            FINI_ARRAY      0001cac0 01cac0 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [11] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        0001cae0 01cae0 000b38 00  WA  0   0 32
  [12] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0001d618 01d618 000098 08  WA  3   0  4
  [13] .got              PROGBITS        0001d6b0 01d6b0 0000d0 04  WA  0   0  4
  [14] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0001d780 01d780 0002c0 04  WA  0   0  4
  [15] .data             PROGBITS        0001da40 01da40 0000d0 00  WA  0   0 32
  [16] .bss              NOBITS          0001db20 01db10 0030dc 00  WA  0   0 32
  [17] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 01db10 000026 01  MS  0   0  1
  [18] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 01db38 0010c0 00      0   0  8
  [19] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 01ebf8 021ada 00      0   0  1
  [20] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 0406d2 009647 00      0   0  1
  [21] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 049d19 00bd3a 00      0   0  1
  [22] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 055a54 004574 00      0   0  4
  [23] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 059fc8 00538c 01  MS  0   0  1
  [24] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        00000000 05f354 01312d 00      0   0  1
  [25] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 072481 0005d0 00      0   0  1
  [26] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 072a51 000101 00      0   0  1
  [27] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 072b54 003530 10     28 504  4
  [28] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 076084 002593 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

If I try to load the file at the address `0x7fab000` then it will relocate the symbols so that the `.text` section starts at 0x7fab000.

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file bios/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.elf 0x7fab000
add symbol table from file "bios/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.elf" at
        .text_addr = 0x7fab000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from bios/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.elf...done.
```

And then all the symbols are off by 0x4c60 bytes.

Answer (score 15):

So, finally, I made my own command with python and the `readelf` tool. It's not very clean since it runs `readelf` in a subprocess and parse its output instead of parsing the ELF file directly, but it works (for 32 bits ELF only).

It uses the section headers to generate and run an `add-symbol-file` command with all the sections correctly relocated. The usage is pretty simple, you give it the elf file and the base address of the file. And since the `remove-symbol-file` wasn't working properly by just giving it the filename, I made a `remove-symbol-file-all` that generate and run the right `remove-symbol-file -a address` command.

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file-all bios/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.elf 0x7fab000
add symbol table from file "bios/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.elf" at
        .text_addr = 0x7fafc50
        .gnu.hash_addr = 0x7fab094
        .dynsym_addr = 0x7fab874
        .dynstr_addr = 0x7face34
        .rel.dyn_addr = 0x7fadf28
        .rel.plt_addr = 0x7faec08
        .plt_addr = 0x7faf170
        .rodata_addr = 0x7fc34e0
        .ctors_addr = 0x7fc7af0
        .dtors_addr = 0x7fc7b00
        .data.rel.ro_addr = 0x7fc7b20
        .dynamic_addr = 0x7fc8658
        .got_addr = 0x7fc86f0
        .got.plt_addr = 0x7fc87bc
        .data_addr = 0x7fc8a80
        .bss_addr = 0x7fc8b60
(gdb) remove-symbol-file-all bios/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.elf 0x7fab000
```

Here is the code to be added in the `.gdbinit` file.

```py
python
import subprocess
import re

def relocatesections(filename, addr):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["readelf", "-S", filename], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

    sections = []
    textaddr = '0'
    for line in p.stdout.readlines():
        line = line.decode("utf-8").strip()
        if not line.startswith('[') or line.startswith('[Nr]'):
            continue

        line = re.sub(r' +', ' ', line)
        line = re.sub(r'\[ *(\d+)\]', '\g<1>', line)
        fieldsvalue = line.split(' ')
        fieldsname = ['number', 'name', 'type', 'addr', 'offset', 'size', 'entsize', 'flags', 'link', 'info', 'addralign']
        sec = dict(zip(fieldsname, fieldsvalue))

        if sec['number'] == '0':
            continue

        sections.append(sec)

        if sec['name'] == '.text':
            textaddr = sec['addr']

    return (textaddr, sections)


class AddSymbolFileAll(gdb.Command):
    """The right version for add-symbol-file"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(AddSymbolFileAll, self).__init__("add-symbol-file-all", gdb.COMMAND_USER)
        self.dont_repeat()

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        argv = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)
        filename = argv[0]

        if len(argv) > 1:
            offset = int(str(gdb.parse_and_eval(argv[1])), 0)
        else:
            offset = 0

        (textaddr, sections) = relocatesections(filename, offset)

        cmd = "add-symbol-file %s 0x%08x" % (filename, int(textaddr, 16) + offset)

        for s in sections:
            addr = int(s['addr'], 16)
            if s['name'] == '.text' or addr == 0:
                continue

            cmd += " -s %s 0x%08x" % (s['name'], addr + offset)

        gdb.execute(cmd)

class RemoveSymbolFileAll(gdb.Command):
    """The right version for remove-symbol-file"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(RemoveSymbolFileAll, self).__init__("remove-symbol-file-all", gdb.COMMAND_USER)
        self.dont_repeat()

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        argv = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)
        filename = argv[0]

        if len(argv) > 1:
            offset = int(str(gdb.parse_and_eval(argv[1])), 0)
        else:
            offset = 0

        (textaddr, _) = relocatesections(filename, offset)

        cmd = "remove-symbol-file -a 0x%08x" % (int(textaddr, 16) + offset)
        gdb.execute(cmd)


AddSymbolFileAll()
RemoveSymbolFileAll()
end
```

Comment: There is a very small improvement you can make: Add `-W` when you call readelf because there are libraries with large section names that get truncated (e.g. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.27.so -> .note.gnu.build-id).

Answer (score 3):

> Can I tell gdb to load all the symbols of all the sections provided that I specify the base address of the file in memory?

Yes, but you need to provide the address of `.text` section, i.e. `0x7fab000+0x00004c60` here. I agree: it's quite annoying to have to fish out address of `.text`, and I wanted to fix it many times, so that e.g.

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file foo.so @0x7abc0000
```

just works. Feel free to file a feature request in [GDB bugzilla](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).

> Does the behavior of gdb make sens?

I am guessing that this is rooted in how GDB was used to debug embedded ROMs, where each section can be at arbitrary memory address.

Comment: If I want to add the symbols of data, I'll have to add the options and addresses of `.data`, `.rodata` and `.bss` sections. And maybe more if I have specific things to debug. I'm writing a pythong script right now to generate the right gdb command.

Comment: @Celelibi No: usually adding `foo.so` with the address of `.text` instead of the load address is *all* you need for both `.text` *and* `.data`.

Comment: No, I just tested, if I don't specify the load address of the `.data` section, the symbols pointing to it get loaded but won't get the offset.

Comment: GDB complains: `A syntax error in expression, near '0x7abc000'.`

Comment: @Yorkwar You are complaining about a missing feature that I *wanted* to fix. I have not fixed it yet, so *of course* GDB complains.

Comment: @EmployedRussian  did you ever add this feature?

Comment: instead of calling readelf via a subprocess, you can use pythons' pyelftool package for parsing elf sections